# MVC - Cache control not working for static content

Tags: c#, caching, model-view-controller, http-headers

In our application, we would like to cache static contents like images, css etc
For security reason, we have added HTTP headers as -

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <!-- Add custom headers to not allow the page content to be cached -->
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
    <add name="Expires" value="0" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

now it was suppose to validate the request and use cache if its validated.
But its not working. Even its a same request, it still loads static content again and again.

I tried adding custom code in config as follows

```
<staticContent>
  <clear/>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:10:00" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpg"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript"/>
</staticContent>
```

Still it does not work.

I dont want to use outputcache.

Is there any option available?

Answer (score 0):

`no-store` disables cache completely [MDN link#1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/headers/Cache-Control#Other), [MDN link#2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/caching#Controlling_caching)

As I understand you need only one header:

```
<add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
```

At first load browser loads a resourse:
[image]
Notice status code is 200 and a response size is 8 KB. Server should add (`IIS` does it automatically) `Etag` header (e.x. `Etag: "8099f82b154d41:0"`)
Then browser caches the file and saves `Etag` value.
On next page reloading browser sends that value as a `If-None-Match` request header (e.x. `If-None-Match: "8099f82b154d41:0"`). Server checks the value and if file is not changed responds with 304 http-code:
[image]
Notice status code is 304 and a response size is 117 B. In that case the cached file is  used.

If file would be changed on the server, server would respond with a new file and 200 http-code, cache wouldn't be used.